# Java Loop to go Through Numbers and Adding 5

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am writing Java code that needs to print these numbers: "0 5 10 3 8 1 6 11 4 9 2 7" in that order. I am new to Java, and am not very good at Loops yet. I am finding the points of a 12 point star, starting at 0, and trying to find the points that need to be touched by a line to make the star..

How do I do a loop that starts at 0, and adds 5 to each number.. so 0 + 5 = 5, 5+5=10, 10+5=3 (this is where my problem is.. How do I make it go back from 11 to 0?

I know this might seem confusing... or it might be extremely easy.. but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably a better question would start from the algorithm you have in mind and what you already tried in java.

Comment: 10+5 = 15, how do you get 3?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is modulus 12 ("12 point star").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment by 5 until you pass 60, display the result of modulo 12. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += 5) {
    System.out.println(i % 12);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. you have really helped me out quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

This is called modulus, and java has the **modulo** operator `%` which gives the remainder of integer division.

```
15 / 12 == 1
15 % 12 == 3
```

as

```
(15 / 12) * 12 + (15 % 12) == 15
```

See the wikipedia.

Of course in your case you could also do

```
n += 5;
if (n >= 12) {
    n -= 12;
}
```

instead of using modulo:

```
n = (n + 5) % 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate from 0 to 12, multiplying your number by 5, and applying modulus 12:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    System.out.println(i * 5 % 12);
}
```

Comment: You rock man.. thanks so much. Learned a lot from reading all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the operator you are looking for is the *[modulus](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html)* operator.  The modulus gives you the remainder from a division problem.  In this case you are using 12 as the denominator.

```
0 + 5 % 12 = 5 (0, remainder 5)
5 + 5 % 12 = 10 (0, remainder 10)
10 + 5 % 12 = 3 (1, remainder 3)
15 + 5 % 12 = 8 (1, remainder 8)
20 + 5 % 12 = 1 (2, remainder 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
for(int i=0;  ; i = (i+5)%12){
    System.out.println(i);
    if(i==7)break;
}
```

Comment: you should explain the solution in words and provide the code snippet as example.